# Plot always starts at 0, highstock spline chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I have data like this

```
var data = [];
for(var i=1;i<201;i++){
   data.push([i,(Math.random() * (80 - 40 + 1)) + 40])
}
```

And I'm creating chart like this:

```
$('.reactivityCont').highcharts('StockChart', {
          chart: {
    marginTop: 140
      },
      credits: {
              enabled: false
          },
          rangeSelector : {
              selected : 1
          },
      scrollbar: {
          enabled: false
      },
      navigator: {
     top : 40,
             xAxis: {
                labels: {
                   formatter: function() {
                      return this.value;
                   }
                }
             }
          },
          xAxis: {
             labels: {
        y: 50,
                formatter: function() {
                   return this.value;
                }
             },
             events: {
               setExtremes: function (e) {
                 start = parseInt(e.min);
         koniec = parseInt(e.max);
         $('.nt').hide();
         for(var i = start-1;i<koniec;i++){
        $('.nt').eq(i).show();
         }
         main();
               }
     }
          },
        series : [{
            type: 'column',
            name : 'reactivity',
            data : data,
    showInLegend: false,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        },
    {type: 'spline',
     name: 'experiment 1',
     data: data2,
     color: 'green',
     visible: false,
     tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
     }
    },
    {type: 'spline',
     name: 'experiment 2',
     data: data3,
     color: 'red',
     visible: false,
     tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
     }
    }
    ],
    legend :{
    enabled: true,
    margin: 0
    },
          rangeSelector : {
             buttons: [
                {
                   type: 'millisecond',
                   count: seqLength/5,
                   text: '0.25'
                }, {
                   type: 'millisecond',
                   count: seqLength/3,
                   text: '0.3'
                 }, {
                   type: 'millisecond',
                   count: seqLength/2,
                   text: '0.5'
                 }, {
                   type: 'all',
                   text: '1.0'
                 }
             ],
             inputEnabled: false, // it supports only days
             selected : 4 // all
          }
    });
```

But unfortunately, my plot starts with 0, but it should not, because there is no such a value.
I tried fix it, e. g. by setting plotOptions:pointStart but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you put it in js Fiddle? Do you get any errors in the console log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by using `column` type series, where columns always starts from 0. To prevent this set `threshold: null`, like this:

```
    series : [{
        type: 'column',
        threshold: null,
        ...
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the`XAxis`'s `min` param.

For Example.

```
 xAxis: {
      labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return this.value;
            }
      },
      min: myInitValue,
      max: myEndValue
 }
```

Hope It Helps.

Comment: It still starts at 0.

Comment: Perhaps it happens by your `setExtremes` function on `events`

Comment: I commented it and nothing changed, still 0.

Comment: Please post it in Jsfiddle and We'll try to help you.